# Oracle database connection in php 5.6 in Ubuntu

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to create an OCI8 connection using php5.6 in ubuntu.
I'm following this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-install-oci8-extension-for-php-oracle-development) for the tutorial.

But I'm getting an error after running the command `pecl install oci8-2.0.10`.
Here is the screenshot of the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNQwu.png).

Comment: It may be better asking this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: There may be something on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805415/oracle-oci8-php5-6-ubuntu-16-04 which may help.

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart whats the response when you type this command?

Comment: @darshanan no response apache is restarting normally.  It is just pecl install oci8-2.0.10 is where I'm getting issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the system PHP:

- Install the 'php-dev' or similar package to get the PHP header files
- Use 'pecl install oci8-2.0.12', since 2.0.12 is the latest version for PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

For php5.6

Note please that this works, but be aware that could be are some unnecesary steps or improvements, I just done this once and had no time to polish it.

This is for a manual installation without pecl command because it seems that is your problem

> 1- Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

In "*Version 12.2.0.1.0*" Section

- "*Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run
  OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications*"

Download **instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip**

- "*Instant Client Package - SDK: Additional header files and
  an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant
  Client*"

Download **instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip**

> 2- Unzip **instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip** and copy to the dir you want i.e :

```
cp -R instantclient_12_2/ /usr/lib/
```

> 3- Unzip **instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip** and copy sdk headers to the dir where you have copied instanclient

```
cp -R ./instantclient_12_2/sdk /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/
```

> 4- Make symlinks :

```
cd /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2
ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so
ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
```

> 5- Configure lib path :

- edit /etc/environment file and insert at the end :
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/instantclient_12_2"
- edit ~/.bashrc file and insert at the end : export
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/instantclient_12_2

> 6- Install dev packages :

```
apt install -y php5.6-dev
```

> 7- Go to https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8

Download **https://pecl.php.net/get/oci8-2.0.12.tgz**

> 8- untar it :

```
tar -zxf oci8-1.4.10.tgz
```

> 9- compile and config :

```
cd oci8-1.4.10
phpize
./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/
make install
```

> 10- enable extension (in this case in fpm)

edit /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini file and insert at the end > extension=oci8.so

> 11- restart service :

```
service php5.6-fpm restart
```

Have fun.

PS: The most helping site that I found while looking for info when I was doing this was http://www.phptutorial.info/?oci8.installation , has explanations to install with/out pecl, manually, etc.